# How to load custom DLL into running AKS pod

Tags: c#, .net-core, architecture, azure-aks, system-design

We have dot net core application which is running in AKS and we need to plug custom DLL into running pod.

About Custom DLL: Customization implemented by each customer which follows certain contracts.

Couple of solutions which we have already explored

1. Upload custom dll in azure blob and load that dll from running pod at runtime to execute the custom code
2. Package dotnet core app image and custom DLL image into one image and deploy it to AKS.

Is there any better way to implement this problem? any industry standard to solve this architecture problem?

Note: Mainly, I am looking for deployment architecture standard and not for implementation details like Reflection or MEF etc.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Images should be immutable artifacts that package and version a set of compiled code.

If your customer drops a custom dll to a storage, then trigger a docker build that will package a version, and run this version.

Doing so will let you run different versions of your dlls, revert to a specific version, or debug locally a specific version.
Loading dynamically from a volume will add some "magic" that will break sooner or later.

My two cents